# laravel 4 packages not working on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some laravel packages built in laravel 4. I tried to use them in Laravel 5 but I keep getting errors when I try to update composer. Some of the errors are:

- don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v-5.0.2
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.2

I'm thinking about rebuilding the packages for laravel 5. I read the documentation but I'm still unsure how to structure the package. Any ideas?

Thank you

Here is my package's composer.json file

```
   {
       "name": "protechmaster/recaptcha",
       "description": "",
       "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Rachid Rafia",
            "email": "rrafiatech@gmail.com"
        }
     ],
      "require": {
         "php": ">=5.4.0",
         "illuminate/support": "*"
     },
     "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
           "Protechmaster\\Recaptcha": "src/"
       }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: Show us your `composer.json`.

Comment: Why not **ping** the author and ask him kindly to update the package given that Laravel 5 was released? ;-)

Comment: I'm the guy who built the packages. I'm trying to update them to laravel 5 with no luck

Answer (score 0):

To use laravel 5 recaptcha try this package:

```
"marwelln/recaptcha": "~2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

this package will help you to solve this problem :
https://github.com/morrislaptop/LaravelFivePackageBridges